# Chirped vs. unchirped pulse and Fourier Transform intuition

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, chirp

Suppose I have a gaussian impulse like in the picture below, given by

$$Ae^{t^2/\sigma^2}e^{j\omega_0 t}$$

[image]

I can do an FFT, add a quadratic phase to it and go back to the time domain. This will result in a chirp as we see in the orange line.

I've always had the intuition that Fourier Transform gives you the amplitude of each frequency in the signal. When I compare the orange and blue lines **visually**, I see that the orange line seems to contain more frequencies than the blue. However, of course, they have the exact same spectrum (in absolute value).

- What is wrong in the intuition above?
- Is this intuition viable at all?
- Is there any valuable information when we look at the peak to peak
  distance in the chirped signal that we can use?

Comment: *I see that the orange line seems to contain more frequencies than the blue* I don't, sorry! *How* do you see that?

Comment: I think this is the root of my problem - it is probably wrong to just look at the peak to peak distances. I think this intuition stems from a simple chirped sine wave of the form sin(at^2) compared to sin(at). How one can see frequencies from a time domain picture? I thought it may be viable to see the peak to peak distance reduce with time and thus we have more frequencies available.

Comment: ah interesting! My intuition worked differently: I looked at the blue curve and saw that it was strongly-time limited, so I inferred that it couldn't be very bandwidth-limited.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that your intuition is wrong, but you can't just look at the oscillations in a time domain signal and try to deduce from it the signal's frequency content. Think of an impulse or a step: no oscillations and *all* frequencies are present.

The blue signal in your figure shows a single oscillation frequency ($\omega_0$), but it has a non-constant envelope, which causes the signal to have a continuous frequency spectrum centered at $\omega_0$. The narrower the envelope, the broader will its effective bandwidth be. The orange signal has a wider envelope, but a range of oscillation frequencies within its (effective) duration. That's how the magnitude spectrum of both signals can be the same.